# LWJGL - difference between GL15 & GL30

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm following ThinMatrix's Opengl tutorial using LWJGL3. There's been lots of `GL15` and `GL30` in the code. What do they mean? Are these different opengl versions? And why do some of them contain fields that the other object does not have. Like `GL15` has the `.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` field yet `GL30` does not despite seemingly coming after `GL15`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespaces refer to the OpenGL versions in which features were introduced (see [OpenGL specification - Khronos OpenGL registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php)  ). OpenGL is backwards compatible (at least with a compatibility profile [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context)). If you use `GL30`, you can also use the implementations of `GL15`. `GL30` does not repeat the implementations contained in `GL15`. So you have to use both namespaces.